# Setting up the Orientation of 3D Text in Arkit application

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I basically have two 3D Points. Let us assume that the coordinates of the two points are:

`(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)` and `(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)`.

Basically, I have three lines:

Line1: directly joins point 1 and point 2. So, end points of this line are:

`(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)` and `(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)`.

Line2: This is basically horizontal component. So,end points of this line are:

`(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)` and `(x: 2, y: 2, z: 1)`.

Line3: This is basically vertical component. So,end points of this line are:

`(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)` and `(x: 1, y: 1, z: 2)`.

Now, I am trying to add a 3D Text. I want to display my text exactly above my line. Since, I have three lines, I will display three texts. So, I would like to know the coordinates of the text (for all the three different lines such that they don't overlap) and also the orientation to be set for the texts (such that they are properly visible always to the user, even if he rotates the mobile etc).

Creating text is as follows:

```
func AddText(pos1: SCNVector3?, pos2: SCNVector3?) {

    var txtNode = SCNNode()
    let d = self.distanceBetweenPoints(A: pos1!, B: pos2!)

    let distanceString = String(format: "%.2f", d)
    let txtGeometry = SCNText(string: distanceString, extrusionDepth: 1.0)

    txtGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

    txtGeometry.alignmentMode  = kCAAlignmentCenter
    txtGeometry.truncationMode = kCATruncationMiddle

    txtNode.removeFromParentNode()
    txtNode = SCNNode(geometry: txtGeometry)

    txtNode.position = SCNVector3(((pos1?.x)! + (pos2?.x)!)/2, ((pos1?.y)! + (pos2?.y)!)/2, ((pos1?.z)! + (pos2?.z)!)/2)

    txtNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.005, 0.005, 0.005)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(txtNode)
}
```

I would be really glad, if some can explain the changes to be made in my above function. So that all the three texts are clearly visible to the user and do not overlap on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your question I am assuming that you want to display your SCNText centrally between your two points and above the line which is placed between them, and respond to the changing position of the camera, e.g. always face the current `pointOfView`.

As such I have created an `SCNNode Subclass` which handles this with relative ease:

```
class TextNode: SCNNode{

    var textGeometry: SCNText!

    /// Creates An SCNText Geometry
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - text: String (The Text To Be Displayed)
    ///   - depth: Optional CGFloat (Defaults To 1)
    ///   - font: UIFont
    ///   - textSize: Optional CGFloat (Defaults To 3)
    ///   - colour: UIColor
    init(text: String, depth: CGFloat = 1, font: String = "Helvatica", textSize: CGFloat = 0.1, colour: UIColor) {

        super.init()

        //1. Create A Billboard Constraint So Our Text Always Faces The Camera
        let constraints = SCNBillboardConstraint()

        //2. Create An SCNNode To Hold Out Text
        let node = SCNNode()
        let max, min: SCNVector3
        let tx, ty, tz: Float

        //3. Set Our Free Axes
        constraints.freeAxes = .Y

        //4. Create Our Text Geometry
        textGeometry = SCNText(string: text, extrusionDepth: depth)

        //5. Set The Flatness To Zero (This Makes The Text Look Smoother)
        textGeometry.flatness = 0

        //6. Set The Alignment Mode Of The Text
        textGeometry.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter

        //7. Set Our Text Colour & Apply The Font
        textGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = colour
        textGeometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        textGeometry.font = UIFont(name: font, size: textSize)

        //8. Position & Scale Our Node
        max = textGeometry.boundingBox.max
        min = textGeometry.boundingBox.min

        tx = (max.x - min.x) / 2.0
        ty = min.y
        tz = Float(depth) / 2.0

        node.geometry = textGeometry
        node.scale = SCNVector3(0.001, 0.001, 0.001)
        node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(tx, ty, tz)

        self.addChildNode(node)

        self.constraints = [constraints]

    }

    /// Places The TextNode Between Two SCNNodes
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - nodeA: SCNode
    ///   - nodeB: SCNode
    func placeBetweenNodes(_ nodeA: SCNNode, and nodeB: SCNNode){

        let minPosition = nodeA.position
        let maxPosition = nodeB.position
        let x = ((maxPosition.x + minPosition.x)/2.0)
        let y = (maxPosition.y + minPosition.y)/2.0 + 0.01
        let z = (maxPosition.z + minPosition.z)/2.0
        self.position =  SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

}
```

An example of how to use this is as follows (note I haven't put a line between the nodes) but nevertheless this should point you in the right direction:

```
/// Generates Two SCNNodes & Places An SCNTextGeometry Between Them
func generateNodes(){

    //1. Create An SCNSphere
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry

    //2. Add The Starter Node And Place It 0.5m To The Left Of Our World Origin
    let starterNode = sphereNode.clone()
    starterNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.5, 0, -0.5)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(starterNode)

    //3. Add The End Node And Place It 0.5m To The Right Of Our World Origin
    let endNode = sphereNode.clone()
    endNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5, 0, -0.5)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(endNode)


    //4. Although We Know The Distance Between The Nodes Is 1m, Calculate It Anyway
    if let formattedDistance = calculateDistanceBetween(starterNode, and: endNode)?.distance{

        //5. Create The Distance Label
        let distanceLabel = TextNode(text: "\(formattedDistance)m", colour: .white)

        //6. Call The TextNode Place Between Nodes Function To Center The Text Between The Nodes
        distanceLabel.placeBetweenNodes(starterNode, and: endNode)

        //7. Add It To Our Scene
        self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(distanceLabel)
    }

}

/// Calculates The Distance Between Two SCNNodes
///
/// -
/// - Returns: (distance: Float, nodeA: GLKVector3, nodeB: GLKVector3)
func calculateDistanceBetween(_ starterNode: SCNNode, and endNode: SCNNode) -> (distance: Float, nodeA: GLKVector3, nodeB: GLKVector3)?{

    //1. Convert The SCNVector3 Positions To GLKVector3
    let nodeAVector3 = GLKVector3Make(starterNode.position.x, starterNode.position.y, starterNode.position.z)
    let nodeBVector3 = GLKVector3Make(endNode.position.x, endNode.position.y, endNode.position.z)

    //2. Calculate The Distance
    let distance = GLKVector3Distance(nodeAVector3, nodeBVector3)
    let meters = Measurement(value: Double(distance), unit: UnitLength.meters)

    print("Distance Between Markers Nodes = \(String(format: "%.2f", meters.value))m")

    //4. Return The Distance A Positions Of The Nodes
    return (distance: distance , nodeA: nodeAVector3, nodeB: nodeBVector3)

}
```

If your'e interested, you can get a more in depth and fully commented example from here: [Measuring In ARKit](https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARKitMeasuring)

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks a lot mate.That really helped a lot! I also have one more query. I have created a function, which can create cylinder.But in some cases it fails. Can I post it is a new question